# Azure DevOps CI/CD - Angular Project - nodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, continuous-integration, angular8, continuous-deployment

[AzureDevOps Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Ee6.png)

Hi, I'm about to do CI and CD for my angular project which is in Azure DevOps Repo.
i"m new to this and referring lots of documentation, i'm still not able to do.
Can some one help to with the step by step procedure ( videos if any) to the below listed pipeline tasks,

> 1) Pipeline,
>   2) Environments, 3) Releases
>   4) Library
>   5) Task Group
>   6) Deployment Groups.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 1)Pipeline

There're two formats of Azure Devops pipelines: Classic(UI) pipelines and Yaml pipelines.

[image]

They have different [feature abilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops#feature-availability). We can create Classic Build pipelines or [multistage Yaml pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-multi-stage-pipeline/) here.

> 2)Environments

The [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) represent a collection of resources targeted for deployment. It's used mostly for CD and it's not available in Classic pipelines, only available in Yaml pipeline.

> 3) Releases

We can create and manage Classic Release pipelines here. Mostly for CD.

> 4) Library

We can use this option to manage some variables group. Normally we can [define pipeline variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline), but those variables are not valid in another new pipeline. To reuse some common variables(Share variables across pipelines), we can consider using Variable Groups under Library.

> 5) Task Group

Similar to Variable Group under Library, it's used to reuse Tasks. If we have many pipelines in which use some similar tasks, we don't need to define the tasks one-by-one each time with Task Groups. See Create a [Task Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops#create-a-task-group).

> 6) Deployment Groups

Check its corresponding document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops):

A deployment group is a logical set of deployment target machines that have agents installed on each one. Deployment groups represent the physical environments; for example, "Dev", "Test", "UAT", and "Production". In effect, a deployment group is just another grouping of agents, much like an agent pool.

**Note:** The `Deployment Groups` in your picture is only supported for Classic Release Pipeline, not yaml pipeline.

> I'm about to do CI and CD for my angular project which is in Azure
>   DevOps Repo.

You don't need to know all the options above when you're new to Azure Devops. A quick-start about Angular project see here:

1.[Build your angular project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops#angular). It could be a simple script like this:

```
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
```

2.To deploy it, you can consider using [Azure Web App Deploy Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-web-app-deploy-task).

Here's one [detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53632633/10910450) about that from **r3plica**. You can easily turn it into classic UI format by using tasks with same names.